# How can I import this txt file into a database table in SqlLiteStudio

Tags: sql, sqlite, data-import

I want to import a text file that looks like this:

[Text file that I need to import into a table](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B80t0h5EO_f3UFBmczVyQVoxSTQ/view?usp=sharing)

It's on 2 columns and I want It to look  exactely like this but in a table.How can I do this?Can someone do this in another program and post It here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press Ctrl+O and ADD new database.

Connect your new database with double click, and right click to show the Option "IMPORT".

Give a table name and click next.

Choose your *.txt file on folder and click next.

Config the CSV behaviour as the picture.

**Choose field separator as (whitespace)**

[image]

Drop the column 2 or replace double space '  ' by single ' ' before import.

[image]

If some data is wrong, repair your textfile in notepad and repeat steps.